# Add password to phpmyadmin without adding a root password

Tags: mysql, apache, phpmyadmin

Is there any way to restrict access to phpmyadmin without adding a password to root (keeping root password as null). May be using Apache configuration files or other method?

Answer (score 0):

As you enter username and password in phpmyadmin authentication screen, phpmyadmin directly try to access database from given username and passwords like

```
$conn = new mysqli(localhost, $username, $password);
```

If mysql returns any Databased associate with this user than phpmyadmin show complete information about this database.

So by default it's not possible to access phpmyadmin using root password null.

But still there are two option

1. Create new Mysql user with all database access privilege keeping your root password null
2. Phpmyadmin is open-source so make changes as per your need.

Answer (score 0):

Sure, you can accomplish this with the normal Apache .htaccess authentication.

For instance, your .htaccess can contain:

```
AuthUserFile /home/Sanjay/.htpasswd-phpmyadmin
AuthName "My custom phpMyAdmin authentication"
AuthType Basic
Require valid-user
```

Then you just have to create the file `/home/Sanjay/.htpasswd-phpmyadmin` (you can use whatever path you wish here, in fact it may not be ideal to put it under your user home directory) using the `htpasswd` command-line program or one of the many online tools. Make sure both files are readable by the webserver and you should be all set.